# Git bogus 'Pull is not possible' message

Tags: git, push

Pushing a commit to the remote origin displays the warning message:

```
remote: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
remote: Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
remote: as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

The push succeeds. There are no unmerged files and the remote branches are up to date. All commits are accurate. The push warning message occurs for every subsequent push.

I tried resetting to a commit prior to when the message occurred, forcing a push, restoring the commits and pushing the changes. I also tried recloning the repository. The message still occurs with every push. The push is from master to the remote origin master.

Comment: what does `git status` output?

Comment: `# On branch master 
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: The problem could only be corrected by deleting the remote repository on the server, creating an empty new repository and issuing a push. This push repopulated the server repository. Subsequent pushes do not show the bogus message. The server repository must have been in an unstable and unfixable state for some unknown reason. Thank goodness every Git clone has a complete history.

Answer (score 2):

This message is almost certainly (I'm certain, anyway) coming from a remote-repository hook.

It sounds like you already tossed out the old remote repo, presumably including its hooks, but if you have them saved somewhere, check for a "pull" operation in the post-receive hook.

Comment: Good point. There is a post-receive hook pull operation on a server clone in order to build documentation. I suspect the problem was the server side synchronization.